# Placement of "is"

Tags: grammaticality

Which sentence of each pair uses "is" correctly?

"Whatever the reason *is*, he just doesn't want to sleep."

"Whatever *is* the reason, he just doesn't want to sleep."

And

"How much do you think *is* it?"

"How much do you think it *is*?"

Answer (score 0):

"Whatever the reason is, he just doesn't want to sleep." is correct.

"Whatever the reason, he just doesn't want to sleep." is also correct, and the "is" is implied. Your other sentence seems unnatural and disjointed.

"How much do you think it is?" is correct.

If you're asking for a definite answer, then use "How much is it?"